# Flatbuffers VerifySizePrefixedBuffer from stream

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

This question is about the correct pattern for reading size prefixed Flatbuffers from a stream in C++.

Consider a data stream - ie. TCP where messages are are delimited by their size prefix. I was initially under the impression that these could be extracted with the following code:

```
while (true) {
  flatbuffers::Verifier v(buf.data(), buf.size());
  if (v.VerifySizePrefixedBuffer<Message>(nullptr)) {
    const flatbuffers::uoffset_t off = flatbuffers::GetPrefixedSize(buf.data());
    const auto msg = flatbuffers::GetSizePrefixedRoot<Message>(buf.data());

    // Use message

    buf.erase(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + 4 + off);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

However, this proves to be incorrect - `VerifySizePrefixedBuffer` checks that the size of the buffer provided to the verifier is *equal* to the size prefix, rather than "at least".

From verifier.h:

```
Check(ReadScalar<uoffset_t>(buf_) == size_ - sizeof(uoffset_t))
```

This means that if there are multiple messages in the buffer, we cannot use the verifier to check that just the first one is valid. Instead, the message size must be read first and provided to the verifier:

```
while (buf.size() >= 4) {
  const flatbuffers::uoffset_t off = flatbuffers::GetPrefixedSize(buf.data());
  flatbuffers::Verifier v(buf.data(), 4 + off);
  if (v.VerifySizePrefixedBuffer<Message>(nullptr)) {
    const auto msg = flatbuffers::GetSizePrefixedRoot<Message>(buf.data());

    // Use message

    buf.erase(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + 4 + off);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

This seems to be duplicating the work of the verifier to check the validity of the prefix. Is there some other pattern I should be using or is this the expected usage?

Comment: Is there an issue with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `verifier` only works on a "completed" buffer, it wouldn't be able to verify a partial buffer. It verifies that all the offsets point to a valid region in the buffer, i.e., you won't attempt to read data not in the buffer.

Say if your first chunk comes in and an `Offset` in that chuck points to some region in the second chunk. The verifier would fail saying that the `Offset` is out of bounds of the buffer it has so far.

The Size Prefix is to help your chunking code to properly receive the length of the buffer and stitch the chunks together. You should use `GetPrefixedSize()` to get the expected size, and then use that to stitch the chunks together until you read that much data. After that, you can use the sized prefix verifier.

You want something like:

```
const auto expected_size = flatbuffers::GetPrefixedSize(buf.data());
while(buf.size() < expected_size) {
  append_to_buf(buf); // however you get your next chunk
}

flatbuffers::Verifier v(buf.data(), expected_size + sizeof(expected_size));
if (!v.VerifySizePrefixedBuffer<Message>()) {
  // ERROR in verification
}
const auto msg = flatbuffers::GetSizePrefixedRoot<Message>(buf.data());

// Use the msg.

// Optionally, consume the buffer to start reading the next message if you have more than one.
buf.erase(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + sizeof(expected_size) + expected_size);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure this really gets at the crux of what I'm asking. `VerifySizePrefixedBuffer` fails if the size of the buffer does not exactly equal `sizeof(expected_size) + expected_size`. So you're forced to pass to the verifier exactly that size - and no more. I'm more questioning this from a design perspective - why does the verifier require you to provide it information that it can deduce itself? A more sensible implementation, IMO, would be that the verifier checks your buffer is at least large enough (and perhaps even had an out argument to return the size it found).

Comment: Ok, so the question is more about the == vs <= check in the verifier than about streaming aspect, and that may just be a bug, I would have to give it some thought it it could break anything.  But on your question about streaming, you still need to call `GetPrefixedSize` on the buff so you know you read enough from the stream to have a complete flatbuffer. That is what I was trying to show in this answer. And once you have the expected size, creating the `Verifier` is just `v(buf.data(), expected_size + sizeof(expected_size))`.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/7956 for this.